# After ajax image is outside the `<a>` tag

Tags: posts, custom-field, ajax

I am loading some content via AJAX, and basically I have this line:

```
$storage .= '<a href='.get_permalink($id).'><img src="'.$image['url'].'" /></a>';
```

Which gets rendered as:

```
<a href="//localhost:3000/story/story-title-wide"></a><img src="//localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/story_wide.png">
```

As you can see the `<a>` is empty and the `img` is rendered afterwards instead of being rendered inside the `<a>`.

The whole AJAX function:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_GET_MORE_STORIES', 'get_more_stories');
add_action('wp_ajax_GET_MORE_STORIES', 'get_more_stories');
function get_more_stories() {

    $nbhd_id = $_POST['nbhd_id'];

    if( have_rows('stories_rep', $nbhd_id) ):

        $row = 0;
        $storage = '';

        while ( have_rows('stories_rep', $nbhd_id) ) : the_row();

            $row++;
            if ($row < 15) { continue; }

            $story = get_sub_field('choose_story');
            $id = $story->ID; 

            $size = get_field('story_image_size', $id);
            if ($size != 'Wide' ) {
                $size_class = '';
            } else {
                $size_class = 'wide';
            }

            $storage .= '<div class="story '.$size_class.'">';

                $story = get_sub_field('choose_story');
                $id = $story->ID; 

                $image = get_field('story_image', $id);
                $storage .= '<a href='.get_permalink($id).'><img src="'.$image['url'].'" /></a>';

                $storage .= '<div class="story-inner">';
                    $storage .= '<h2>'.get_the_title($id).'</h2>';
                    $storage .= '<a class="needtext" href='.get_permalink($id).'></a>';
                    $storage .= '<div class="line"></div>';
                $storage .= '</div>';

            $storage .= '</div>';

        endwhile;

    else :

        $storage = '';

    endif;

    echo $storage;
    die();

}
```

Comment: Share Ajax code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, with **"** tags on `.= '<a href="'.get_permalink($id).'"><img src="'.$image['url'].'" /></a>';`